# ASP.NET CORS blocking font request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I built an ASP.NET Web API service and enabled CORS in that service. This service is used for serving report templates resources `(html, image, css, font)`. The web client loads the template and display report based on downloaded template.

So, given the service enpoint: `http://templates.domain.com`, 
and I try access the service `(REST, Image, Font)` from a web app (`http://client.domain.com`), then the web client app will load:

- `http://templates.domain.com/templates/:templateName`
- `http://templates.domain.com/templates/:templateName/css/style.css`
- `http://templates.domain.com/templates/:templateName/image/header.jpg`
- `http://templates.domain.com/templates/:templateName/font/test.ttf`

In the above, the REST API, CSS, and images from the service working well, but the font is blocked/failed.

> Font from origin 'http://localhost:49350' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null'

So far, I've tried the solutions below, but the font is still blocked.

1. `Microsoft.Owin.Cors`:

   `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`
2. `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`:

   `var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);`

Comment: Do you have the font extensions defined in your frontend web.config file? I get a 404 (not CORS error) if I do not define them, so perhaps this is not the issue. e.g. <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" /></staticContent</system.webServer>

Comment: @S. Baggy no 404, just CORS error

Comment: Could you post the request/response headers?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255255/10030693

Answer (score 9):

Are you using OWIN or WebAPI?

For a AspNet WebAPI the following would allow everything through:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

It is important to point out that allowing "*" is potential security vulnerability as you are saying anyone from anywere can invoke these methods.