# How to enable cors in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project?

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

Configured CORS in my ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project. But the preflight request receives a http 405 error.

In other words HTTP OPTION is not allowed. Looks like cors is not enabled.

I've seen examples with `config.EnableCors();` but there is no `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` in this project template.

What am I missing here?

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var devCorsPolicy = "devCorsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(devCorsPolicy, builder => {
        //builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:800").AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        //builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");
        //builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true);
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseCors(devCorsPolicy);
}
else 
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    //app.UseCors(prodCorsPolicy);
}

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: BTW, `app.UseCors(devCorsPolicy);` line is being hit.

Comment: Are you **sure** this is on .NET Core 2.2 ?? The code looks more like the "simplified" templates included in .NET (Core) 6.0 ....

Comment: It's the web api version on .NET 6

Comment: Where are you getting CORS errors? In the browser or in swagger?

Comment: @MaartenDev First saw it in the browser and now testing with postman with same result.
CORS headers are not added and preflight gets http 405

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for the edits

Comment: Did you try moving the UseCors just above MapControllers outside the if?

Comment: @MaartenDev Just tried it, same result

Comment: I just copy and pasted your entire `Program.cs` into a fresh .NET 6 project and the CORS works fine. Could you try creating a fresh .NET 6 project and placing your question content in`Program.cs`?

Comment: You're right @MaartenDev,
Checked again with the browser and it works. 
For some reason postman preflight always returns http 405. If you'll post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you posted seems to work fine. I pasted the code into a new .NET 6 project and the CORS headers are added in the response when a request like below is send from the browser.

```
fetch('http://localhost:7107/Weatherforecast').then(res => res.json()).then(e => console.log(e))
```

Results in the following response:
[image]

Answer (score 56):

Add service `builder.Services.AddCors` and app add `app.UseCors("corsapp");`

replace  `builder.WithOrigins("*")` with `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:800", "https://misite.com");`

check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    
    // Add services to the container.
    
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    //services cors
    builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
    }));
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
        
    }
       //app cors
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("corsapp");
        app.UseAuthorization();

        //app.UseCors(prodCorsPolicy);

    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

Comment: It's important to note that the `UseCors` invocation must be placed between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` invocations if they are present.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Of course, order is always important in services.

Answer (score 8):

This CORS thing can be a headache to set especially for the first time. But by being precise you can do.

In your `Program.cs` file, make the following change. Notice that there are two changes to be made one above and another below the `var app = ...` statement:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(policyBuilder =>
    policyBuilder.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
        policy.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod())
);

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors();
```

If you are specifying an actual origin, make sure you include the `http` part for example:

```
...
policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
```

Your web browser code making the request should also be in point. Here is the request in javascript using axios:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = 'http://localhost:5000'

/**
 * 
 * @returns {TransferHeader[]}
 */
export const fetchTransfers = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${api}/api/transfers`,
        // withCredentials: true
    })
    console.log(data)
    return data 
}
```

Setting cors is only required when the api is being called by the web browser. If the calls are coming from the server like it is for nextjs' server components, setting up cors may not be required

Answer (score 3):

For anyone making the same mistake as me:
Make sure your client application calling the Web API has the correct url with `https://` scheme. So `localhost:8100/api` should be `https://localhost:8100/api`.

Comment: ooooooooooh bro. That was my problem also. I was struggling with CORS, but it was all about the correct url. Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue that I believed the wildcard option works out of the box for ports too. When I set the correct port it worked. (`http://localhost:*` does NOT work!)

```cs
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(AllowCorsPolicyName,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .WithOrigins(
                            "http://localhost:5173",
                            "http://localhost:5174",
                            "https://*.example.com",
                            )
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });
```

```cs
        // With endpoint routing, the CORS middleware must be configured to execute between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints.
        app.UseCors(AllowCorsPolicyName);
```

Docs can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0

When using `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and you call the http endpoint it will also not work

Answer (score 2):

Works with me

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
.AllowCredentials());
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference to Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

You've to follow some steps to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

1. In Program class :

   - Set a policy name "It's optional but 'll help you to avoid repeat write it multi times".

     ```
     var  MyAllowedOrigins = "_myCORS";
     ```
   - Configure CORS service.

     ```
     builder.Services.AddCors(options =>{
          options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowedOrigins ,
                  policy  =>
                  {
                      policy.WithOrigins("Write URL here")
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowCredentials());
                  });
           });
     ```
   - Add CORS Middleware to handle cross-origin requests before authorization.

     ```
     app.UseCors(MyAllowedOrigins);
     ```