# Failed to enable CORS in asp .net core 6.0 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working a asp .net core 6.0 web Api.(We are moving to asp .net core from 3.1 to 6.0)

I did enable cors in our asp .net core 6.0 project and works fine earlier (this morning ). But Now I faced cors error.

**Error:**
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

I revoked my git commits and checked. still It give CORS error

This is my program.cs

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("*")/*.AllowAnyOrigin()*/.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The same code worked fine earlier in asp .net core 6.0.
Also Now In asp .netcore 3.1 project It is working fine.

Note: I searched about this error. And Tried same as on this answer [How to enable cors in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511588/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-6-0-web-api-project). But It did not work for me.

What  is the mistake I did?
Why this error occurs ( Today morning I did not face this error. But now facing this error. I revoked my new commits too. But CORS error)

**Is there any other reasons to get this CORS error. I guess mistake is on my asp.net core 6.0 project, because asp .net core 3.1 project is working fine**

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ClientPermission", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("ClientPermission");
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

Comment: try with above code

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 4):

app.UseCors should come after app.UseRouting();

according to the official documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax

```
            builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>  opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", c =>
            { 
                c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
            }));

         .....

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")
```

Comment: I tried with this. But not working for me.

Comment: I faced a similar problem - have you checked whether your browser needs a Cors Unblock extension? I was facing Cors related issues until I installed and activated the Edge extension Cors Unblock.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `web.config`.  It worked for me with .NET Core 5.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
            </modules>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"   />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\project.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 043EE210-85D7-4EA4-A1CB-4FA6BCD39F0A-->
```