# Angular app making HTTP request to Net Core api gets blocked by CORS policies

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core

My requests have been blocked by CORS policies, I have the following in my startup class:

```
         services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder => {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
```

I'm using an Nginx server and I always get the following error when I make a request with my angular app:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any help is really appreciated!

**Edit**

I made some changes suggested in the code, but I got the same error. The changes made were the following:

```
         services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "corsapp",
                builder => {
                    builder
                        .WithOrigins("https://myurl/", "https://myurl2/")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
```

And in the Configure method:

```
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("corsapp");

        app.UseAuthorization();
```

`myurl` and `myurl2` are two urls that make requests to the api, both have the same domain, but different subdomain

Comment: which version of .net core are you using?

Comment: I'm using net core 6

Comment: check this link out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511588/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-6-0-web-api-project  It basically says create a policy, and then add  app.UseCors("THE_POLICY_YOU_CREATED");

Comment: I just tried that out, and I got the same response :(

Comment: make sure you write app.UseCors("WHATEVER") before you use app.MapControllers() or app.UseMvc()

Comment: Yes, I have it before mapcontrollers, I'm gonna update the post with that information

Comment: try adding the app.usecors() before app.userouting and instead of adding urls, just use builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); to see if you can get it working with that.  At least then you will know it is your url's that are broken

Comment: I just made all those changes, but same result. Nothing changed

Comment: is your angular app running on localhost:4200 ? if so, add `http://localhost:4200` to "WithOrigins" method

Comment: No, it is already published

Comment: Are you using `UseAuthorization` in your code? If yes, The call to `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`. See Ref: [CORS with named policy and middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).