# How to fix Axios Network error in React.js & ASP.NET Core 6.0?

Tags: reactjs, axios, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to implement a system using React.js and ASP.NET Core 6.0 and wanna display the user detail of the session on front end.
I use Axios to connect the front end to my back end and get an Axios Network Error.

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:****/api/home' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried to use full url (https://localhost:3000/) and there is still an error.
How can I fix this error?

Thanks!

**HomeController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace test.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public class UserDetail
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult login()
        {
            UserDetail user = new UserDetail();
            user.Name = User.Identity.Name;

            return Ok(user);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            user: []
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("https://localhost:****/api/home").then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);  
                this.setState({
                    user: response.data.user,
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });  
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div key={this.state.user.name}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: You need to enable CORS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable cors in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70511588/283366)